# Full Body A/B Split Workout Review

Tags: workout-routines, muscle-mass, hypertrophy, splits

I've been working out for a while now, doing different programs (SL 5x5, GZCLP, various full body routines).
Since my weeks vary in busyness and I want to throw in some other activity occasionally (like bouldering or running), I'm trying to get away from any routines dictating a fixed amount of days per week. Instead, I'm looking for something like an A/B split workout I can do 2 or 3 times a week depending on how busy I am, without missing out on body parts if I do 2 (and yes I do know that less will still be less, but at least every major muscle group would be worked once in a week) or overdoing it.

Since I haven't found such a routine which is (IMO) sensibly programmed and I really like, I came up with my own. I would really appreciate an honest review, pointing out missing volume, improper exercise selection and any other flaws.

**Workouts**

As mentioned above, this is meant as an A/B Split Full Body workout. I would ideally work out 3 times a week, if I'm busy only 2 times. So two optimal weeks would be: week 1 = A/B/A, week 2 = B/A/B. The goal was to create rather "sweet and short" workouts, where I can keep the intensity up and hit a lot of muscles simultaneously with compound movements, instead of throwing in a ton of volume and isolation. The main goal is hypertrophy.

| Workout A | Workout B |
| --- | --- |
| 1. Squat: 4x8-10 + 1 Drop-Set @ 50-60% 2. DB Bench Press: 3X8-12 3. Superset, 3x: - Military Press: x8-12 - Pull-Up: x5-10 4. Superset, 3x, no rest between supersets: - Hanging Leg Raise: x10-15 - Band Pull-Apart: x20 | 1. Deadlift: 3X5 (last set AMRAP) 2. Superset, 3x: - Incline Bench Press: x8-12 - Barbell Row: x8-12 3. Superset, 3x: - (Reverse) DB Lunge: x8 (each leg) - DB Bicep Curl: x8-12 4. Superset, AMRAP, 10sec between supersets: - W Raise (abs exercise, see e.g. AthleanX): x5 - Twisting Sit-Up: x16 |

**Progession Scheme and Stalling:**

I do have some tactics for progression and handling stalls, inspired by typical bodybuilding principles, SL 5x5 and GZCLP. For progression, I would add reps and/or  weight. Failures are handled by retrying the next workout and after repeated failing (stalling) eventually going down in weight (SL 5x5) or switching the rep scheme (GZCLP). I won't go into detail to keep the question shorter, but could elaborate in a comment if requested.

Thanks in advance for any reviews and suggestions, if you know any good established programs that would fit my goal I would also appreciate suggestions.